# uitableview case sensitive sections

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am wondering how to get my get the different case letters to go into the same sections...

I pass my parsed data over to a custom method that takes the array and creates the section letters as shown bellow.. I'm just not sure how to make it so that capital and non capital letters appear in the same sections and was hoping for some help.

```
//method to sort array and split for use with uitableview Index
- (IBAction)startSortingTheArray:(NSArray *)arrayData
{
     //If you want the standard array use this code
    sortedArray = arrayData;

    self.letterDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    sectionLetterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Index scrolling Iterate over values for future use
    for (NSString *value in sortedArray) 
    {
        // Get the first letter and its associated array from the dictionary.
        // If the dictionary does not exist create one and associate it with the letter.
        NSString *firstLetter = [value substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];

        NSMutableArray *arrayForLetter = [letterDictionary objectForKey:firstLetter];
        if (arrayForLetter == nil) 
        {
            arrayForLetter = [NSMutableArray array];
            [letterDictionary setObject:arrayForLetter forKey:firstLetter];
            [sectionLetterArray addObject:firstLetter]; // This will be used to set index scroller and section titles
        }
        // Add the value to the array for this letter
        [arrayForLetter addObject:value];
    }      
    //Reload data in table
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

this is what it looks like atm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to always store just the uppercase (or lowercase) version of the first letter.  So you could do something like:

```
        NSString *firstLetter = [[value substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] uppercaseString];
```